# Alert when data-rel="back" is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a simple button on a popup implemented in my webpage with `data-rel="back"`

I need to get an alert when the back button (dat-rel="back") is clicked. Is there a way to determine this? I tried to add to every class selector a click event but it wont work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ui-icon-left").click(function() {
    alert("clicked");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-icon-left ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-left">Click</a>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `.ui-icon-left` is added dynamically when jQM auto-initializes the page. OP, `.ready()` should never be used in jQM; listen to `pagecreate` instead. It seems you're trying to prevent closing a popup, it can't be achieved this way. You need to hijack "close button" when you first open it and then close it manually.

Comment: @Omar apologies - I missed the jquery-mobile tag

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no worries :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible answer to your current question:

```
$(document).on("vclick", "[data-rel=back]", function(e) {
    console.log("Clicked!!!");
});
```

Don't know what you are tring to do, but, as Omar correctly pointed out in a previous comment, you can't prevent this way a `popup` from closing.

If you have a `popup` with mandatory fields, maybe you can remove the `data-rel="back"` link, add `data-history="false"` and `data-dismissible="false"` to your `popup` markup and create  your own close button where you can execute the necessary tests and close the `popup` manually.

Comment: To be more specific and to avoid affecting other elements with `rel=back`, add `.ui-popup` to selector, in order to target only popups. `.ui-popup [data-rel=back]`. Edit: to hijack close button, `event.preventDefault()` and then add your logic.